# Changing text within a <Div>

Tags: html

Have some issue with coding here. If there is no class assigned to the  tag, how can I change the content using a external script? I would like to change the addition operator.

```
<tr>
<td><div id="number1">1</div></td>
<td><div>+</div></td>
<td><div id="number2">2</div></td>
<td><div>=</div></td>
<td><input type="text"></input></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Check"></input></td>
```

Thank you

Comment: In your own page, you want to change content of one div to another text? In that case you need to use JavaScript/jQuery. And this change should ocure on what event? On a button click?

Comment: Use id if no class assigned to tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use like

```
     var elem = document.getElementById("number1"); /*this will get the  div element for which you want to change the text. "number1" can be any ID*/
     elem.innerHTML="123" /* this will update the text of that div*/
```

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
<td><div id="number1">1</div></td>
<td><div>+</div></td>
<td><div id="number2">2</div></td>
<td><div>= <span id="result"></></div></td>
<td><input type="text"></input></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Check"></input></td>
```

Jquery code :

```
$(function(){
    $('#result').text('your text here ....');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to change the markup client-side using JS or similar - I've provided some examples below using jQuery.

The most robust solution would involve changing the markup so that there is some identifying feature of the DIV, so for example adding a class, e.g.

```
<td><div class="operator">+</div></td>
```

Once you have that, you can select the element and change its content with jQuery like this:

```
jQuery('.operator').html("added to");
```

If you can't change the markup then you need to find some other way of identifying the element.

Without access to your whole markup it's difficult to say reliably what the best way will be, but here's one example based on the markup you provided. It works by finding the second TD element within each TR element.

```
jQuery('tr td:nth-child(2)').html("added to");
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/